# Rails: must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm following along Bate's tut on graphs & charts but am getting an error.

This is the error I'm getting

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "orders.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT created_at, sum(amount) as total_amount FROM "orders"...
               ^
: SELECT created_at, sum(amount) as total_amount FROM "orders"  WHERE ("orders"."created_at" BETW
```

And this is the code I'm using in my Orders model

```
def self.total_grouped_by_day(start)
    orders = where(created_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)#.all
    orders = orders.group("date(created_at)")
    orders = orders.select("date(created_at), sum(amount) as total_amount")
    orders.group_by { |order| order.created_at.to_date }
  end
```

and in my helper

```
def orders_chart_data
        orders_by_day = Order.total_grouped_by_day(3.weeks.ago)
        (3.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
            {
                created_at: date,
                price: orders_by_day[date].first.try(:total_amount) || 0
            }
        end
    end
```

---

I'm using Postgres (which I'm pretty sure is the main reason I'm getting this error) & Rails 3.x.x.
Why is this error occurring & how do I fix it?

Thank you in advance

---

In my console:

```
Order.where(created_at: 3.weeks.ago.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now).group("date(created_at)").select("date(created_at), sum(amount) as total_amount")
```

& this is what I get

```
[#<Order >, #<Order >, #<Order >]
```

weird..

---

running this in my console: `Order.where(created_at: 3.weeks.ago.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now).group("date(created_at)").select("date(created_at), sum(amount) as total_amount").first.total_amount`

gives me this:

```
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method Order.page.
  Order Load (18.1ms)  SELECT date(created_at), sum(amount) as total_amount FROM "orders" WHERE ("orders"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-07-05 00:00:00.000000' AND '2013-07-26 23:50:38.876609') GROUP BY date(created_at) LIMIT 1
 => "10.0"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are grouping on `date(created_at)` but not selecting that column.  Change this line:

```
orders = orders.select("created_at, sum(amount) as total_amount")
```

to this:

```
orders = orders.select("date(created_at), sum(amount) as total_amount")
```

That will also result in a change to the next line's group_by as well.

From one of my projects, using slightly different attributes, but doing the same thing as you:

```
1.9.3p327 > User.group('date(created_at)').select('date(created_at), sum(id) as total_amount').first.attributes
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT date(created_at), sum(id) as total_amount FROM "users" GROUP BY date(created_at) LIMIT 1
 => {"date"=>"2011-09-27", "total_amount"=>"657"}
```

Comment: I actually tried this at first but am getting this error `missing attribute: created_at`

Comment: Getting that error in the next group_by line?  You will.  You need to look at what you're getting back before you do that group_by as it probably isn't what you want anymore.  Remember, you tweaked the select so that column isn't being returned anymore.

Comment: Right, so I should change it to `orders.group_by { |order| order.date(created_at).to_date }` right? I'm not sure because after doing that, I get `undefined local variable or method `created_at' for #<Class...`

Comment: No.  You should look to see what is returned before you call that.  My memory is you'll get a hash.  Keys will be the string value of "date(created_at)" and values will be the remaining arguments.  But I could be totally wrong about that.  Check the docs and try it in the console.

Comment: please see my question. I edited in what I'm getting in my console.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to inspect those individual objects. What happens if you run that and append ".first.total_amount"?  You might need to change your select to return named columns so you can reference them like you did with "sum(amount) as total_amount".

Comment: @jon see my updated answer.  i've mimicked what you're doing on one of my own projects.  I'm summing the ID field (ridiculous, but it's an integer) but you can see how it works and what is being returned.

Comment: Ok, I see now. I'm using 'created_at' instead of 'date' but now that just leads me to another problem *sigh*... I'm getting `undefined method 'first' for nil:NilClass` error in my helper (see question)

Comment: I'll figure it out though... Thank you @Philip

Answer (score 0):

A cast to date would be simplest & fastest. Here the raw SQL since I am no expert with Ruby syntax (and no fan of ORMs butchering SQL in general).

```
SELECT created_at::date, sum(amount) AS total_amount
FROM   orders
WHERE  created_at ...
GROUP  BY created_at::date
ORDER  BY created_at::date
```